# Cloud Composer - DAG error: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: bigquery

Tags: apache-spark-sql, airflow, google-cloud-dataproc, google-cloud-composer

I'm trying to execute a DAG which create a Dataproc Cluster at Cloud Composer. But It fails when trying to save on Big Query. I suppose that is missing a jar file ( --jars gs://spark-lib/bigquery/spark-bigquery-latest_2.12.jar) but I don't know how to add to my code.

code:

```
submit_job = DataprocSubmitJobOperator(
        task_id="pyspark_task", 
        job=PYSPARK_JOB, 
        location=REGION, 
        project_id=PROJECT_ID)
```

If a call this job at the Cluster, it works.

`gcloud dataproc jobs submit pyspark        --cluster cluster-bc4b       --jars gs://spark-lib/bigquery/spark-bigquery-latest_2.12.jar        --region us-central1       ~/examen/ETL/loadBQ.py`

But I don't know how can I replicate on Airflow

Code on PySpark:

`df.write   .format("bigquery")     .mode("append")   .option("temporaryGcsBucket","ds1-dataproc/temp")   .save("test-opi-330322.test.Base3")`

Answer (score 1):

In your example

```
submit_job = DataprocSubmitJobOperator(
        task_id="pyspark_task", 
        job=PYSPARK_JOB, 
        location=REGION, 
        project_id=PROJECT_ID)
```

The jars should be part of `PYSPARK_JOB` like

```
PYSPARK_JOB = {
    "reference": {"project_id": PROJECT_ID},
    "placement": {"cluster_name": CLUSTER_NAME},
    "pyspark_job": {
      "main_python_file_uri": PYSPARK_URI,
      "jar_file_uris": ["gs://spark-lib/bigquery/spark-bigquery-latest_2.12.jar"],
    },
}
```

See this [doc](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/_modules/airflow/providers/google/cloud/example_dags/example_dataproc.html).